# command 'jpm run' is not working

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I have installed jpm in my system. Now I changed the things I wanted to in index.js. Next I used command 'jpm run'. Some error is coming on like this:

```
JPM [info] Starting jpm run on erp
Creating XPI
JPM [info] XPI created at C:\Users\RAJATR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\@erp1-0.0.1.xpi (
47ms)
Created XPI at C:\Users\RAJATR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\@erp1-0.0.1.xpi

JPM [info] Creating a new profile

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

                ^

Error: spawn REG ENOENT

    at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

As you may see, here the xpi file is created but however some error come and I could not understand the details. Help me. I am very sure that codes are alright. Because I used that xpi file created in my firefox browser which is working absolutely fine.

Comment: This is real weird. Were you able to figure it out yet?

Comment: The name of your xpi looks weird, did you not give your add-on a name in the `package.json` or set the `id` to `""`? That *could* be the reason

Comment: Could you try to copy the files to a new addon directory to see if the error persists? If yes, could you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a path to firefox, using

```
jpm run -b <path>
```

where `<path>` can be, for example,

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

(Windows)
or

```
 /usr/bin/firefox
```

(Linux)